# Mesos + Docker, do I automatically get the benefits of Mesos HA, etc.?

Tags: docker, mesos, marathon

Mesos now supports Docker. If I run Docker as an Executor, do I still get some of the high-availability and scheduling benefits of Mesos? Or do I have to run Docker tasks e.g. within Marathon to get this?

What would be the benefit of using Mesos + (native) Docker instead of just plain Docker without Mesos? I understand the idea of using Mesos + Marathon + Docker tasks because I get the HA and failover benefits.

Answer (score 3):

Mesos natively supports Docker images as executors within your framework. The benefit of this is that you can now deploy a docker container without having to be aware of the internal topology of your server cluster. With just Docker, you have to connect to the exact remote host and do system-specific configuration.

As for HA, you will need to use a meta-framework (like Marathon, Docker Swarm, etc) in order to monitor your instances and configure redundancy and fault-tolerance. With Marathon this is trivially easy, and works by default.